# How do i get Sumifs to return a null value if the cell is null over multiple ranges

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've been struggling with this for a while now, I use a `SUMIFS` in excel to evaluate over a range of data.

My problem is that it returns the blank cells as zeros instead of blank, 
is there a way to make the cell return as blank when looking at multiple ranges?

[image: Data]

The above picture is what the data looks like and the below one is what the `SUMIFS` returns, I need it to return blanks where the data is blank instead of zero:

[image: Sumifs]

The formula I use is
`=SUMIFS(Sheet1!C:C;Sheet1!$A:$A;Sheet2!$A2;Sheet1!$B:$B;Sheet2!$B2)`
where sheet 1 is the sheet with the data and sheet 2 is the table where the `SUMIFS` evaluates.

Also if the value is blank in the data it must return blank, but if it is zero in the data it must return as a zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat similar to [User91504’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1260536/150988#1260541), use

`=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$A:$A;Sheet2!$A2; Sheet1!$B:$B;Sheet2!$B2)=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$A:$A;Sheet2!$A2; Sheet1!$B:$B;Sheet2!$B2; Sheet1!C:C;""); ""; SUMIFS(Sheet1!C:C; Sheet1!$A:$A;Sheet2!$A2; Sheet1!$B:$B;Sheet2!$B2))`

This is

```
=IF(X=Y; ""; Z)
```

where

- *`X`* is `COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$A:$A;Sheet2!$A2; Sheet1!$B:$B;Sheet2!$B2)`,
  which is the number of cells that your `SUMIFS` is summing over.
- *`Y`* is
  `COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$A:$A;Sheet2!$A2; Sheet1!$B:$B;Sheet2!$B2; Sheet1!C:C;"")`,
  which is the number of cells that your `SUMIFS` is summing over
  *that are blank*.
- *`Z`* is
  `SUMIFS(Sheet1!C:C; Sheet1!$A:$A;Sheet2!$A2; Sheet1!$B:$B;Sheet2!$B2)`,
  which is your original `SUMIFS` formula.

If *`X`* = *`Y`*, that means all of the cells you are looking at are blank,
so display blank. 
Otherwise, there is at least one non-blank cell,
so you want to display the sum, even if it is zero.

Comment: *As usual* with Excel formulas, the argument separator depends on your region / localization settings.  I used semicolons (`;`) in my answer because that’s what the OP uses in the question. Most (?) of the [SU] population — users in English-speaking countries — will need to replace the semicolons with commas (``,``).

Comment: @RickyD accept as correct answer, I will delete mine as it did not work for you